# Resizable window in electron.js

Tags: node.js, electron

I am making small code editor and i want  user to be able to resize window if user wants. I have main window property non resizable.
 `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600 ,  resizable: false});`
I have button
I have drop down menu :

```
 label: 'Screen',
    submenu:[
      {
        label:'Resizable Window',
        click(){
          mainWindow.resizable = false;
        }
      },
```

My code doesn't work. Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change if a window is resizable you have to call [`mainWindow.setResizable(false)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetresizableresizable) instead of `.resizable = false`.

And it seems that you're setting resizable to false when it's already false, I think you want to set it to true to enable resizing.

In summary you would end up with something like:

```
label: 'Screen',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Resizable Window',
    click () {
      mainWindow.setResizable(true);
    }
  },
],
```

[`.setResizable`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetresizableresizable) Docs.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my button in the top right corner still doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by it still doesn't work? Like does it throw an error or just does nothing? Can you also edit your post to include your full menu bar code, thanks

Comment: There is a button like open in  the full screen and it is still disabled(it is windows default button )